# Apply custom doctrine output walker by default to all queries

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I have written the following custom walker to use postgres's ilike instead of like:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class IlikeWalker extends SqlWalker
{
     /**
     * Walks down a SelectClause AST node, thereby generating the desired SQL.
     *
     * @param $selectClause
     * @return string The SQL.
     */
    public function walkLikeExpression($likeExpr)
    {
        $sql = parent::walkLikeExpression($likeExpr);
        $sql = str_replace('LIKE', 'ILIKE', $sql);
        return $sql;
    }
}
```

which may be added to any query via:

```
      $query->setHint( $query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER
                     ,'\DoctrineExtensions\WalkerBundle\Walker\IlikeWalker' );
```

But how do I start a service or apply a config to automatically use this for every query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doctrine 2.5 has a new option `defaultQueryHint` on orm configuration. You can setup a custom walker once for all queries:

```
<?php
/** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em */
$em->getConfiguration()->setDefaultQueryHint(
    Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
    '\DoctrineExtensions\WalkerBundle\Walker\IlikeWalker'
)
```

You can use this code in `boot` method of your bundle class:

```
class YouBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        $this->container
            ->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
            ->getConfiguration()
            ->setDefaultQueryHint(
                Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
                '\DoctrineExtensions\WalkerBundle\Walker\IlikeWalker'
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't globally set this hint. So to solve your problem i see two ways:

1) register and use your own doctrine function for ILIKE (example here https://github.com/domudall/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Dmno/DoctrineExtensions/Comparison/Postgresql/Ilike.php)

2) Use AOP interceptor (https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) to insert `$query->setHint..` before every execute of a query.

Comment: To bad there is no solution.  I'll accept this because while it does not solve the problem it provides path forward.  I'll checkout the xtension later.